# Mealy FSM using T flip flops

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, flipflop

So I am to design a mealy state machine which detects the sequence 101. The state diagram was given, and from there I obtained the flip-flop excitation equations. I am supposed to use 2-1 multiplexers to implement the excitation equations, but I am having difficulty tying this together with T flip flops. I don't want anyone to do my assignment for me (which is why I'm only asking for theoretical answers), but I am a bit stuck as to how to approach this.

Comment: Have you tried DeMorgans theorem to expand the equation into something early implementable with MUX's?

Comment: The issue was not implementation using MUX's. Turns out I was over thinking it and that those equations were T1 and T0 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The steps from diagram to circuit are:

1. Create the state transition table

   - state before (name, encoded)
   - inputs (external, internal)
   - flipflop input (T)
   - flipflop output (Q)
   - state after (name, encoded)
2. Fill in states (before, after) regarding your diagram
3. encode each state in the diagram. E.g. binary or one-hot
4. Double all lines for each external input
5. Fill out the Q columns (identical to state after, because Q saves the state)
6. Use the T-FF transition table to fill out the T columns.

FF transition tables:

```
D-FF
Q -> Q' | D
-----------------
0    0   |  0
0    1   |  1
1    0   |  0
1    1   |  1

T-FF
Q -> Q' | T
-----------------
0    0   |  0
0    1   |  1
1    0   |  1
1    1   |  0
```

These tables describe how D or T must be driven to change Q to Q'.

Last step: The equations use all inputs (external and internal) and produce T.